# Is downvoting associated with keeping the site "clean"?

Tags: discussion, voting, moderation

Okay. So in the past, I have asked many bad questions. I mean they were bad. But one comment, on a certain question that has been deleted, said this about me:

> 340 up, 84 down. Not exactly stellar 'keeping the site clean' :(

I wondered if downvoting means you are contributing more to the site. To be exact there are a lot of "crappy" questions.

Sure, I have written a bunch too. But that was part of the learning process, of course. Now high reputation users are remarking that downvoting means you are keeping the site clean and you are contributing more.

**P.S:** Is that what the commentator meant or am I just misinterpreting it?

Also, can't upvoting be interpreted as helping good answers come top? Why is there this general opinion?

Comment: The comment should have been flagged. It is not needed.

Comment: @rene I didn't know who was right at that point. It had actually two helpful votes received too. Was that deliberate?

Comment: There's not really an answer in response to your concern about the comment outside of "flag the comment." We have no way of knowing what that user was trying to say without some context around the conversation.

Comment: I don’t understand why people downvote someone that asks for our expert understanding of how Stack Overflow works. By downvoting do you wish to signal “we don’t want people to ask us for help understanding how Stack Overflow works?” Because that’s how it comes across.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While I would find it difficult to accept that any one contributor could be seen as keeping the site "clean" without having a *few* downvotes...the comment itself is unnecessary and entirely orthogonal to any conversation that was present, due to it being an attack on your character.

**The comment should be flagged.**

Comment: I agree with your opinion that somebody who tries to help the community has to have a few downvotes. For example, I now have 125 downvotes. Which for me is pretty good as I been contributing at SO for the previous 4 months.

Comment: Of course it can't be flagged now, as the question has been deleted.

Comment: If you can find it and link to it, anyone with 10k+ rep can see it *and* flag it @GauravMall.

Comment: Here is the link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388829/is-moderation-getting-a-bit-over-board

Comment: Attacks on the character of ALL curators is very common.  It's especially annoying when coming from posters with skewed, and so unrealistic/ineffective voting patterns.

Answer (score 19):

> I wondered if downvoting means you are contributing more to the site.

You are contributing to the site using all your available privileges, be it voting, flagging, editing.

Whether you or others like it or not, the Stack Exchange Q/A model is designed with quality in mind. That does mean you need to signal to both poster and future visitors how to judge the post. You can't simply rely on *thumbs up* to be enough to differentiate good and sub par posts. Down votes serve that goal.

If I recall correctly that comment was posted on a meta question of yours where you complained about moderation with the roaring title [*Is moderation getting a bit over-board?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388829/is-moderation-getting-a-bit-over-board#comment723940_388829) where you advocated that your personal needs at the time had higher priorities then the rules we established here in the last 6 to 8 years.

In that context the comment tried to convey the notion that if you start a discussion about moderation, you have to be prepared to look at your own contribution. Some users believe that everything can be solved with down votes and with enough of them SO will become a better place. Some moderators believe you need to delete all the things and SO will become a better place. Some believe you need to edit all the things and the welcoming wagon will ride. Some believe a thumbs up and a hug is enough to curate a canonical knowledge base for many visitors to come.

**tl;dr;** All moderation privileges exist and assist to make SO posts useful for many visitors. Ideally you should use each and every tool in the right context. When you discuss moderation here, take all aspects in account, not only the ones you like or dislike.

Flag comments that are targeting you instead of your post.

Comment: You are right indeed; the cup may be half-full or half-empty. The comment (should) may be flagged as suggested by [@Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389011/6381711), but one may need to assess further than the *words* shared and get the *message* communicated.

Answer (score 12):

Occasionally, some people might look at a user's total number of upvotes and downvotes, in order to make certain (usually not very constructive) remarks.

It's a fact that casting votes, up and down, is a key piece of curating the site. Downvotes too, as they leave a signal of something being not right. Also, since most of the incoming questions have issues, it is common for an active curator to have a larger number of downvotes than upvotes. Therefore, someone may choose to publicly recognise someone as a non-curator based on the low ratio between upvotes and downvotes, suggesting then that they could be assisting the site better.

The other way around may also happen: someone judging a user over the large number of downvotes, linking them with being negative or grumpy.

Both statements are pointless (the latter being ridiculous) and it's better not to leave these comments at all: curation work, although valuable and definitely not deserving a demonizing look, is also voluntary, so we'll have to accept that people may not wish to take the role.

Comment: I have every sympathy with those not wishing to take the role, and none whatsoever with users in that set who criticize all those curators who do put in a lot of volunteer effort.

Comment: @MartinJames Patience is a virtue. Let us show that at least we can have a level head despite all the overreactions from those who do not know better.

Answer (score 4):

Without going into assessment what poster of that comment meant, there are few facts that not all SO users are familiar with:

- Continuous posting of poor content can lead to question or answer ban - which means you can no longer post poor content.
- There is a system for automatic removal of poor questions that satisfy some conditions:  [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered, zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/313443) - based on that rules down voted questions and questions without up voted and accepted answers are easier to remove because some of them will be automatically deleted.
- Every person with moderating privileges (that can cast close votes, or delete votes) has limited amount of daily votes.

Above can have impact on voting behavior for people that participate in moderating more:

- Once you are out of close votes and you encounter poor content you might down vote as part of moderation
- When you start participating in moderation (for instance, using various moderation queues) you will encounter more poor content that does not belong to the site (and for the reasons stated above) you may feel it deserves down vote in order to be cleaned sooner.
- Down voting helps in preventing people to post poor content again.
- Down voting helps in removing poor content faster.
- It is easier to recognize poor content even in areas you are not an expert - which can also influence voting behavior. For good content unless you are an expert, or you have similar problem as the question you are up voting, or particular answer works for you, you cannot know for sure whether question or answer are really good or not. Of course if you are not sure then you will probably not vote at all.

**Some conclusion:**

While you can certainly participate in moderating and keeping the site clean without casting any down vote ever, people that participate in moderation will usually have more down votes than up votes.